# Count the number of possible ways to solve an equation

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

This question was asked in a challenge in HackerEarth:

> Mark is solving an interesting question. He needs to find out number
>   of distinct ways such that
>   **(i + 2*j+ k) % (x + y + 2*z) = 0**, where **1 <= i,j,k,x,y,z <= N**
>
> Help him find it.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> 1<= T<= 10
>
> 1<=N<= 1000
>
> **Input Format:**
>
> First line contains T, the number of test cases. Each of the test case
>   contains a single integer,N in a separate line.
>
> **Output Format:**
>
> For each test case , output in a separate line, the number of distinct
>   ways.
>
> **Sample Input**
>   2
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> 1
>
> 15
>
> **Explanation**
>
> In the first case, the only possible way is i = j = k = x =y = z = 1

I am not getting any way how to solve this problem, I have tried one and I know it's not even close to the question.

```
import random

def CountWays (N):

    # Write your code here
    i = random.uniform(1,N)
    j = random.uniform(1,N)
    k = random.uniform(1,N)
    x = random.uniform(1,N)
    y = random.uniform(1,N)
    z = random.uniform(1,N)
    d = 0
    for i in range(N):
        if (i+2*j+k)%(x+y+2*z)==0:
            d += 1
    return d

T = int(input())

for _ in range(T):

    N = int(input())

    out_ = CountWays(N)
    print (out_)
```

> My Output
>
> ## 0
>
> ## 0
>
> Instead it should give the output
>
> ## 1
>
> ## 15

Comment: Just FYI, you can edit your question so that you don't have to delete and repost. Thanks for providing the code as text!

Comment: yeah I had edited the question but it was closed by other two people, thank you for the info

Comment: If this gets downvotes and/or closure votes, the reason is likely because it feels a bit like a "here's some code and it doesn't work" question, so you might consider elaborating a bit on your thought process/approach and showing some failing inputs/outputs, etc.

Comment: I'm betting this code will run too long... There's a more formal way to check if `(x + y + 2*z)` evenly divides `(i + 2*j+ k)`

Comment: Some math on my end led me to note that we're essentially dealing with the range of:

{4, ..., 4N} % {4, ..., 4N}. Given this, we should be able to take a quarter of this range, ie {4, ..., N} % {4, ..., N}

Comment: @cricket_007 it would be great help, could you suggest some

Comment: What is `T` and it's relation to the equation? What does number of testcases have to do with the solutions?

Comment: just to print the T number of outputs for T number of inputs@user2653663

Comment: Looking at your code it seems like that `T` is a list of values for `N`, and the constraint `1<=T<=10` is not a constraint on `T` but on `len(T)`. You should edit your  question to make this clear.

Comment: T is just an integer to identify no of test cases, considering the only given testcase the T is 2, so the for loop will iterate 2 times and the first N is 1 and the second N is 2 , the question is clear and I just pasted the question as it was in HackeEarth challenging question @user2653663

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the numerator (`num`) can range from 4 to 4N. The value of the denominator (`dom`) can range from 4 to `num`. You can split your problem into two smaller problems: 1) How many values of the denominator is a given value of the numerator divisible by? 2) How many ways can a given denominator and numerator be constructed?

To answer 1) we can simply loop through all the possible values of the numerator, then loop over all the values of the denominator where `numerator % denominator == 0`. To answer 2) we can find all the [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of the numerator and denominator that satisfies the equality and constraints. The number of ways to construct a given numerator and denominator will be the product of the number of partitions of each.

```
import itertools

def divisible_numbers(n):
    """
    Get all numbers with which n is divisible.
    """
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            yield i
        if i >= n:
            break

def get_partitions(n):
    """
    Generate ALL ways n can be partitioned into 3 integers.
    Modified from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/218332-generator-for-integer-partitions/#c9
    """

    a = [1]*n
    y = -1
    v = n
    while v > 0:
        v -= 1
        x = a[v] + 1
        while y >= 2 * x:
            a[v] = x
            y -= x
            v += 1
        w = v + 1
        while x <= y:
            a[v] = x
            a[w] = y
            if w == 2:
                yield a[:w + 1]
            x += 1
            y -= 1
        a[v] = x + y
        y = a[v] - 1
        if w == 3:
            yield a[:w]

def get_number_of_valid_partitions(num, N):
    """
    Get number of valid partitions of num, given that
    num = i + j + 2k, and that 1<=i,j,k<=N
    """
    n = 0
    for partition in get_partitions(num):
        # This can be done a bit more cleverly, but makes
        # the code extremely complicated to read, so
        # instead we just brute force the 6 combinations,
        # ignoring non-unique permutations using a set
        for i,j,k in set(itertools.permutations(partition)):
            if i <= N and j <= N and k <= 2*N and k % 2 == 0:
                n += 1
    return n

def get_number_of_combinations(N):
    """
    Get number of ways the equality can be solved under the given constraints
    """
    out = 0
    # Create a dictionary of number of valid partitions
    # for all numerator values we can encounter
    n_valid_partitions = {i: get_number_of_valid_partitions(i, N) for i in range(1,4*N+1)}

    for numerator in range(4,4*N+1):
        numerator_permutations = n_valid_partitions[numerator]
        for denominator in divisible_numbers(numerator):
            denominator_permutations = n_valid_partitions[denominator]
            if denominator < 4:
                continue
            out += numerator_permutations * denominator_permutations
    return out

N = 2
out = get_number_of_combinations(N)
print(out)
```

The scaling of the code right now is very poor due to the way the `get_partitions` and the `get_number_of_valid_partitions` functions interact.

**EDIT**

The following code is much faster. There's a small improvement to `divisible_numbers`, but the main speedup lies in `get_number_of_valid_partitions` not creating a needless amount of temporary lists as it has now been joined with `get_partitions` in a single function. Other big speedups comes from using `numba`. The code of `get_number_of_valid_partitions` is all but unreadable now, so I've added a much simpler but slightly slower version named `get_number_of_valid_partitions_simple` so you can understand what is going on in the complicated function.

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def divisible_numbers(n):
    """
    Get all numbers with which n is divisible.
    Modified from·
    """
    # We can save some time by only looking at
    # values up to n/2
    for i in range(4,n//2+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            yield i
    yield n

def get_number_of_combinations(N):
    """
    Get number of ways the equality can be solved under the given constraints
    """
    out = 0
    # Create a dictionary of number of valid partitions
    # for all numerator values we can encounter
    n_valid_partitions = {i: get_number_of_valid_partitions(i, N) for i in range(4,4*N+1)}

    for numerator in range(4,4*N+1):
        numerator_permutations = n_valid_partitions[numerator]
        for denominator in divisible_numbers(numerator):
            if denominator < 4:
                continue
            denominator_permutations = n_valid_partitions[denominator]
            out += numerator_permutations * denominator_permutations
    return out

@numba.njit
def get_number_of_valid_partitions(num, N):
    """
    Get number of valid partitions of num, given that
    num = i + j + 2l, and that 1<=i,j,l<=N.
    """
    count = 0
    # In the following, k = 2*l
    #There's different cases for i,j,k that we can treat separately
    # to give some speedup due to symmetry.
    #i,j can be even or odd. k <= N or N < k <= 2N.

    # Some combinations only possible if num is even/odd
    # num is even
    if num % 2 == 0:
        # i,j odd, k <= 2N
        k_min = max(2, num - 2 * (N - (N + 1) % 2))
        k_max = min(2 * N, num - 2)
        for k in range(k_min, k_max + 1, 2):
            # only look at i<=j
            i_min = max(1, num - k - N + (N + 1) % 2)
            i_max = min(N, (num - k)//2)
            for i in range(i_min, i_max + 1, 2):
                j = num - i - k
                # if i == j, only one permutations
                # otherwise two due to symmetry
                if i == j:
                    count += 1
                else:
                    count += 2

        # i,j even, k <= N
        # only look at k<=i<=j
        k_min = max(2, num - 2 * (N - N % 2))
        k_max = min(N, num // 3)
        for k in range(k_min, k_max + 1, 2):
            i_min = max(k, num - k - N + N % 2)
            i_max = min(N, (num - k) // 2)
            for i in range(i_min, i_max + 1, 2):
                j = num - i - k
                if i == j == k:
                    # if i == j == k, only one permutation
                    count += 1
                elif i == j or i == k or j == k:
                    # if only two of i,j,k are the same there are 3 permutations
                    count += 3
                else:
                    # if all differ, there are six permutations
                    count += 6

        # i,j even, N < k <= 2N
        k_min = max(N + 1 + (N + 1) % 2, num - 2 * N)
        k_max = min(2 * N, num - 4)
        for k in range(k_min, k_max + 1, 2):
            # only look for i<=j
            i_min = max(2, num - k - N + 1 - (N + 1) % 2)
            i_max = min(N, (num - k) // 2)
            for i in range(i_min, i_max + 1, 2):
                j = num - i - k
                if i == j:
                    # if i == j, only one permutation
                    count += 1
                else:
                    # if all differ, there are two permutations
                    count += 2
    # num is odd
    else:
        # one of i,j is even, the other is odd. k <= N
        # We assume that j is odd, k<=i and correct the symmetry in the counts
        k_min = max(2, num - 2 * N + 1)
        k_max = min(N, (num - 1) // 2)
        for k in range(k_min, k_max + 1, 2):
            i_min = max(k, num - k - N + 1 - N % 2)
            i_max = min(N, num - k - 1)
            for i in range(i_min, i_max + 1, 2):
                j = num - i - k
                if i == k:
                    # if i == j, two permutations
                    count += 2
                else:
                    # if i and k differ, there are four permutations
                    count += 4

        # one of i,j is even, the other is odd. N < k <= 2N
        # We assume that j is odd and correct the symmetry in the counts
        k_min = max(N + 1 + (N + 1) % 2, num - 2 * N + 1)
        k_max = min(2 * N, num - 3)
        for k in range(k_min, k_max + 1, 2):
            i_min = max(2, num - k - N + (N + 1) % 2)
            i_max = min(N, num - k - 1)
            for i in range(i_min, i_max + 1, 2):
                j = num - i - k
                count += 2

    return count

@numba.njit
def get_number_of_valid_partitions_simple(num, N):
    """
    Simpler but slower version of 'get_number_of_valid_partitions'
    """
    count = 0

    for k in range(2, 2 * N + 1, 2):
        for i in range(1, N + 1):
            j = num - i - k
            if 1 <= j <= N:
                count += 1
    return count

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = int(sys.argv[1])
    out = get_number_of_combinations(N)
    print(out)
```

Comment: thank you so much, the way you have explained the algorithm in few words, superb, appreciate   your hard work......

Comment: "I will try post a better scaling version tomorrow." Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ebad See edit. The code should run in at most a few seconds with `N=1000`.

Answer (score 0):

The current issue with your code is that you've picked random numbers once, then calculate the same equation N times.

I assume you wanted to generate 1..N for each individual variable, which would require 6 nested loops from 1..N, for each variable

Now, that's the brute force solution, which probably fails on large N values, so as I commented, there's some trick to find the multiples of the right side of the modulo, then check if the left side portion is contained in that list. That would only require two triple nested lists, I think

Comment: yes you assumed correctly, however I could not find any other way that's why took the random and that too I took it in a wrong way

Comment: my question is by looking at this problem how am I gonna approach or what should be the algorithm to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
(i + 2*j+ k) % (x + y + 2*z) = 0, where 1 <= i,j,k,x,y,z <= N

(2*j + i + k) is a multiple of (2*z + x + y)
```

N = 2

```
min(2*j + i + k) = 4
max(2*j + i + k) = 8

ways to make 4: 1 * 1 = 1
ways to make 5: 2 * 2 = 4
ways to make 6: 2 * 2 = 4
ways to make 7: 2 * 2 = 4
ways to make 8: 1 * 1 = 1
```

Total = 14

But 8 is a multiple of 4 so we add one more instance for a total of 15.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you got the ways to make 5,6,7

Comment: @YouKnowWhoIAm sure. For the equal or larger side, we get `5: {2*1, 1, 2} or {2*1, 2, 1}`, `6: {2*1, 2, 2} or {2*2, 1, 1}`, `7: {2*2, 1, 2} or {2*2, 2, 1}`, each of which are multiplied by the number of ways to make the equal or smaller side, which are the same.

Comment: earlier it was going over my head, now it's clear thank you @גלעדברקן